# Reset key of object and retain value

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working with a super-small library that builds key/value objects. The libraries code can be found here https://github.com/scaraveos/keyval.js/blob/master/keyval.js

There's a number of ready-built functions for setting/deleting keys and values. However there's no function for updating a given key.

I'm trying to create one, but not having much luck. This is what I'm trying to do.

```
var kv = new keyval();

var key = "This is a key";
var key2 = "test";
var value = "This is the value";

kv.set(key, value);

var reset = kv.set(key, key2);
var get1 = kv.get(key);
var get2 = kv.get(key2);

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = get1.v;
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = get2.v;
```

and here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mmK9V/

If someone can help me on this, I'd be super appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by creating a new keyvalue object with key2,value1 and then removing key1 from the container:

```
function resetKey(kv, key1, key2) {
     var value1 = kv.get(key1);
     kv.set(key2, value1);
     kv.del(key1);
}
```

After calling this function, key1 does not exist in the container and instead you have key2 which has the same value that key1 used to have.